# Finding the max value of a variable in SAS per ID per time period

Tags: sas, time-series

```
 proc sql;
create table abc as select distinct formatted_date ,Contract, late_days
from merged_dpd_raw_2602
group by 1,2
;quit;
```

this gives me the 3 variables I\m working with

they have the form

|ID|Date in YYMMs.10| number|

```
proc sql;
create table max_dpd_per_contract as select distinct contract, max(late_days) as DPD_for_contract
from sasa
group by 1
;quit;
```

this gives me the maximum number for the entire period but how do I go on to make it per period?

I'm guessing the timeseries procedure should be used here.

```
proc timeseries data=sasa
                out=sasa2;
by contract;
id formatted_date interval=day ACCUMULATE=maximum ;
trend maximum ;

var late_days;

run;
```

but I am unsure  how to continue.

I want to to find the maximum value of the variable "late days" per a given time period(month). So for contact A for the time period jan2018 the max late_days value is X.

how the data looks:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee3MZ.jpg

Comment: Does a specific contract id appear only once in the data when grouped by `date`, `contract`, `days_late`.  Or is the data multiple points in time (dates) for a contract, each date having the corresponding days late that is occurring on the date.  You can use proc MEANS and CLASS statement to have aggregate values computed for various class combinations.  Improve the question -- provide sample data, your code, its results and desired results

Comment: @richard There are multiple daily point in time for a contract, each contract having a days late value. I want to to find the maximum value of the variable "late days" per a given time period(month). So for contact A for the time period jan2018 the max late_days value is X. I will edit my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you will want to calculate your aggregate within a group that uses a computed month value.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2021);

  length contract date days_late 8;

  do contract = 1 to 10;
    days_late = 0;
    do date = '01jan2020'd to '31dec2020'd;
      if days_late then 
        if rand('uniform') < .55 then 
          days_late + 1;
        else
          days_late = 0;
      else
        days_late + rand('uniform') < 0.25;

      output;
    end;
  end;
  format date date9.;
run;

options fmterr;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select 
    contract
  , intnx('month', date, 0) as month format = monyy7.
  , max(days_late) as max_days_late
  from
    have
  group by
    contract, month
  ;
```

You will get the same results using `Proc MEANS`

```
proc means nway data=have noprint; 
  class contract date;
  format date monyy7.;
  output out=want_2 max(days_late) = max_days_late;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the proc means method and it got me reading about proc means and how to  better use it.